# alert message when open internet explore in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, browser, rubygems, alert

I am new for rails and In my rails app I want to give alert message when user open app using internet explorer. I know I can use    [browser Gem](https://github.com/fnando/browser).

But I have no idea where to use it to detect the browser application wise. can any one help me for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are following the correct hierarchy, then all your controllers are inheriting ApplicationController. Add a `before_action` filter to your application controller and perform the checks to probably redirect to a page where you want to show a message. Sounds good?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :detect_ie_and_redirect
  
  private def detect_ie_and_redirect
    if gem_check_passes?
      redirect_to :some_path # or show some message if you want
    end
  end
end
```